# How to create account with multiple aliases?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-directory-api

I'm attempting insert a new user into our org and this user has multiple aliases.  Google_Service_Directory_User has a facility to "setAliases". On insert, the account is provisioned properly with all the attributes set correctly, minus the aliases - those aliases just seem to be ignored.

```
$dirObj = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

$primaryEmail  = 'joeschmo99@my.test.domain.com';
$alias1        = 'joetest1@my.test.domain.com';
$alias2        = 'joetest2@my.test.domain.com';

$firstName     = 'Joe';
$lastName      = 'Schmo99';
$shaPass       = sha1($someRandomPass);

$nameObject = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName();
$nameObject->setGivenName($firstName);
$nameObject->setFamilyName($lastName);
$nameObject->setFullName("$firstName $lastName");

$userObject = new Google_Service_Directory_User();
$userObject->setName($nameObject);
$userObject->setPassword($shaPass);
$userObject->setHashFunction('SHA-1');
$userObject->setPrimaryEmail($primaryEmail);
$userObject->setAliases( array( $alias1, $alias2 ));

$results = $dirObj->users->insert($userObject);

print_r($results);
```

Any suggestions for inserting a new user with aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing almost everything right except for the alias insertion. Let's go over this step by step.

1. First you create the directory object and then the user object:

   ```
   $service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

   $userObj = new Google_Service_Directory_User(
     array(
       "name" => array("givenName" => "Joe", "familyName" => "Schmo99"),
       "primaryEmail" => "joeschmo99@my.test.domain.com",
       "password" => $shaPass
     )
   );
   ```
2. Next, you insert the user object in the account and save the returned primary email to a variable:

   ```
   $newUser = $service->users->insert($userObj);
   $createdUser = $newUser->primaryEmail;
   ```
3. Create an array of the user aliases you want to assign:

   ```
   $userAliases = array("joetest1@my.test.domain.com", "joetest2@my.test.domain.com");
   ```
4. Loop through the array, create a user alias object for each alias email and insert them to the user object:

   ```
   foreach ($userAliases as $userAlias) {

       $newAlias = new Google_Service_Directory_Alias(
         array(
           "alias" => $userAlias,
         )
       );

       $service->users_aliases->insert($createdUser, $newAlias);

   }
   ```

Please don't forget to review the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases/insert) on how to insert aliases for a better and more detailed explanation. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I was attempting to set it on insert, but the other method will work too. thanks for the example.